# Navbar resizing based on screen size

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make my navbar (and logo) shrink when scrolling down on larger screens where the mobile menu button is not visible (> 768px), and have it remain at a fixed smaller size on smaller screens.

Standard Bootstrap 3 classes for the HTML, the javascript I have right now that doesn't seem to be working the way I want is below. It is applying the nav resizing that I want but on all screen sizes. I want it to only apply the changes on the larger screens.

```js
function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
                $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("shrink-nav");
                $(".navbar-brand img").addClass("shrink-logo");
            } else {
                $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("shrink-nav");
                $(".navbar-brand img").removeClass("shrink-logo");
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("shrink-nav");
        $(".navbar-brand img").addClass("shrink-logo");
    }
}

resize();
```

The CSS I am using for the modifier classes is below.

```css
.shrink-logo {
    position: relative;
    height: 60px;
    top: 15px;
}

.shrink-nav {
    height: 70px;
    padding: 15px 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You added the shrink-nav class in both your if and else blocks when you calculated the window size. So it will be applied at all window sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code snippet..I think this will help you...

```
resize();
$( window ).resize(resize);
function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
         if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
             $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("shrink-nav");
             $(".navbar-brand img").addClass("shrink-logo");
         } else {
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("shrink-nav");
            $(".navbar-brand img").removeClass("shrink-logo");
         }
     } else {
         $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("shrink-nav");
         $(".navbar-brand img").addClass("shrink-logo");
     }
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't do what I wanted it to but I was able to produce the results I wanted with removing the else portion of the function and a media query in css, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
resize();
$(window).resize(resize);
$(window).scroll(resize);

function resize() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
         if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
             $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("shrink-nav");
             $(".navbar-brand img").addClass("shrink-logo");
         } else {
            $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("shrink-nav");
            $(".navbar-brand img").removeClass("shrink-logo");
         }
     } else {
         $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("shrink-nav");
         $(".navbar-brand img").addClass("shrink-logo");
     }
 }
```

Comment: It's doing something weird, the navbar will collapse into the smaller one after I start scrolling on the smaller screen, but then when i switch back to a larger screen it will stay small until I start scrolling again.

The site at the link below shows how I want mine to basically behave, if you look at it in responsive view.

https://www.hammerpackaging.com/our-products

Comment: try to add resize listener. $( window ).resize(resize);

Comment: Thanks for the response, which line should I add that too? Sorry I'm still a little new to jQuery.

Comment: you could also use a css transition on the height